# Keep the font and size same all over the webpage/script

Tags: html, css, forms, fonts

I wrote a php script which include php code, html and javascript and contains form and tables and div tags. I want to make the **font to Arial and size to 3 everywhere throughout the form and in table or in labels**. **Even in selection box option entries and text boxes(whenever user enter a value it should be in Arial and size 3) .**

**Only I want to overwrite the font size to a different one in certain places only when I want.

How can I change the font to Arial and the size to 3 everywhere in the html and php webpage and user entering fields.

Thank you.

Comment: Use CSS with * as selector.

Comment: What does "size 3" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
<style>
  *{
      font-size:3px;
      font-family: arial;
   }
</style>
```

If this style is overwrite by another style then you can use it as `!important`

You can use it in `.css` file of your project OR include it in header file in `<style></style>`

Comment: Hi Kevin Thanks for this. Is this the full style code under the style tag?. how to use this in the whole web page/script?

Comment: Yes. It works. What is the overwrite style code and how to use in a particular field?.Thanks

Comment: Can you give me your link then only i can tell you where to put this style.

Comment: The page is not online. But I want the following place to make the font size to 5 and face to Calibri.                               <tr>
<td><input type="text" id="book_title" size="80" class="content" value = "<? echo "$myrow_c[1]" ?>" /></td>
</tr>

Comment: Then use `*{
      font-size:5px;
      font-family: Calibri;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

if you have using external css then write a style code in that file like this:

```
    html, body, div, table, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, img, label, footer, header, span, pre, iframe  /* write any other tag that you are using in your page */
    { 
       font-size: 3px;
       font-family: arial;
       //any other style that you want 
    }
```